# geting values from query object in php

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I know how to retrieve all the object values in TWIG, but how do I access them in plain php from the query object. Something like $display->item or $display.item, but none of these works. Am i missing something here?

```
        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT obj
                FROM AppBundle:itemInfoDb obj
                WHERE obj.sku = :sku'
                )->setParameter('sku', $nextSku)
                ->setMaxResults(1);

        $display = $query->getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *getters* methods for access to property: `$display->getItem()` for instance. BTW, you can use better the `getOneOrNullResult()` method to do that:

```
// Get exactly one result or null
$object = $em->createQuery($dql)
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->getOneOrNullResult();

if (null !== $object) {
    $object->getId();
}
```

The difference is that `getSingleResult()` not allows empty result so throws `NoResultException` exception.

Otherwise, you need catch the exception:

```
try {
    // Gets the single result of the query.
    $object = $em->createQuery($dql)
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getSingleResult();

    $object->getId();
} catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
    // null result
}
```